# Dilemma about Money

Tags: dilemma

I earn well enough. But I don't count how much my money I spend. I mostly spend money on just foods only. But here is the problem. If I cook myself at home, I can save a lot of money. However, I spend twice / thrice the same amount if I spend eating outside. Well, the extra amount I could donate for good purposes. But, I don't want to cook at home as I need to wash the utensils and make necessary arrangements that would take my time. I am confused about what should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Buddhist financial management is as follows:

[image]

[Sigal’ovada Sutta](http://www.themindingcentre.org/dharmafarer/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/4.1-Sigalovada-S-d31-piya.pdf)

> (1) personal and family use (eg support of parents, spouse, children, servants, and visiting family
>   friends and colleagues);
>
> (2) for the benefit of friends (including entertainment of guests and clients);
>
> (3) invest in security and insurance;
>
> (4) the fivefold offering (pañca,balī): given to relatives, to guests, to the departed, to the government (as payment of taxes, etc), and to devas;
>
> (5) for supporting worthy religious (Dharma work).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to donate, but if you want then why not.

> I mostly spend money on just foods only.

If you don't have money when you what to do charity you just need to wash your dishes and do the preparations. It does not have to be much.

**Donations** helps the dharma stay alive, it will cultivate good karma, it will help Dharma to flourish and prosper. If Dharma is helping you it will help you more if its strong and bigger. It will also help you to be more detached from money for a better cause. I think